# What's a possible reason why someone might need to teach another person how to program?

Tags: computers

In schools teachers teach because it's their job.
Parents teach their children things because they want the best for their offspring.

What would be a good reason why one person/friend may want (or need) to teach another person/friend how to program?
If the person teaching can already write code one would think that it'd be easier for him/her to write code to solve a problem than take the time and teach it to someone else.
Anyone know of a good reason (besides from the kindness of their heart)?

Comment: There is another SE for this, its like interpersonal relationships or something

Comment: Why are there teachers?

Comment: This is off-topic for this thread

Comment: I can imagine reasons about why this may be on-topic here (maybe an incipit of a story about hacking or AIs?). However, even if on-topic, it is definitely both too broad and opinion based.

Comment: I thought this was about Sci Fi story building. Well, CS kind of relates to Sci Fi and I am trying to build a story on it-  not sure why this is off topic

Comment: Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: @AndresAlvarez this site is about world-building in general - you're right. You build a world, you encounter a problem you cannot solve, you ask. Your question is not really about a specific problem but more about looking for ideas (which, in general, we don't really condone on this site). In addition you are asking for 'a good reason' - this is very *opinion-based* (another thing we don't like). Any answer is as good as the next one, as there is no criteria on what differentiates a good answer from a bad one. So everything is completely arbitrary (guessed it, we don't like arbitrary....).

Comment: So, as you have not yet done so, please take the [tour] :)

Comment: Andres, as you learn to understand this site you'll discover it is filled with amazingly creative people.  However, the site does have a specific goal.  We focus on the subset of storybuilding called worldbuilding.  Regrettably, that means this site is not about storybuilding.

Answer (score 1):

We are social animals and associations work much better if we share knowledge and abilities.

Any *sane* firm/society has programs for "continued education" of its members; otherwise their usefulness would decline with time.

A certain number of (IMHO insane; reasons for this are outside the scope of this Answer) firms actually rely on turnover to get the skill they need.

This is true for *any* association; I might be a skilled programmer, but:

- teaching programming to my spouse might better our family income.
- teaching programming to a friend/neighbor I see often might halve my programming burden.
- I might be working at home and teaching programming to someone nearby might provide a person with which talk when I get stuck somewhere.

As you see all these might work as well with other skills beyond programming and none of them involve pure "kindness".

Comment: *"provide a person with which talk when I get stuck"* Get a rubber duck, or a teddy bear, or a penguin plushy, or whatever else you fancy. If you have one, you can even discuss the problem with your pet. It's far faster than first teaching someone else to program, and a lot of the time, also just as effective. I'm not making this up, [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is a real thing!

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I *am* a programmer and I *am* aware of the power of just explaining to the house cat (that is what I'm doing routinely) exactly what the problem is. I am also often working from home and I assure you having around someone who understand what you're saying may be a relief, sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I am a skilled programmer, but I do not have enough time to write programs for everyone else, especially friends and relatives, who I would generally not think of charging anyway.

If I teach them to program, it takes some of the heat off of me - in practice, they still come to me with programming problems, but these are usually relatively easier for me to solve, less time-consuming, and more interesting.

Since I have to make a living from programming and other associated skills, where I am not being directly paid for this it makes sense to try to get people self-sufficient.